# Determine which numeric column definition is the most precise

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, types

I am looking to determine which column type amongst multiple columns is the most precise as to coalesce the data into one unioned column. The types can vary across numerical types: `float`, `long`, `double`, and varying precisions and scales of `decimal`. My question is, how can I determine which is the "most precise" as to not lose data due to truncation during the conversion? An example, I have columns as such:

```
decimal(10,0)
decimal(18,3)
decimal(10,6)
long
double
float
```

I need to union all these columns into one datatype that will not lose any data. What would be the resulting datatype? My thought is `decimal` > `double` > `float` > `long` so the resulting type would be `decimal` then we take the max scale `6` and add it to the max precision `18` minus that max precision's scale `3` to get a type `decimal(21, 6)`. This would preserve 6 places to the right of the decimal for column 3 but also allow 15 to the left of the decimal for column 2.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? I'd expect the dbms to chose the correct result data type.

Comment: It's a Spark application with explicit typing (cant join different data types). I'm trying to build the schema of underlying tables populated by different sources with their own types. I have to convert these values from text files into the unified type

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer to this question, because `float` and `double` have ranges much larger than the rest.  So, you might have to settle on `double` *just to represent the values at all*.

A `long` has a range up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, which is 19 digits.  So, the first four types are all compatible with `decimal(26, 6)`.  That might be sufficient for the `float`/`double` as well, but you really need to investigate the ranges of the values.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I was thinking that may be best case. 98% of the time there is no difference between sources, but it's that 2% that causes issues. I think a cast to double could be safe in specific conditions.